# Open sets in a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y=[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology. Indicate whether the following sets are open in: $\mathbb{R}$, $Y$ with the subspace topology, in $Y$ with the order topology given by the order induced from the order on $\mathbb{R}$.

$(\frac{1}{2},1)$, $[\frac{1}{2},1)$

---

We know that the standard basis of $\mathcal{T}_{stand}$ is $\mathcal{B} := \{(a,b)\mid a<b, \;a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$. For a set to be open in $\mathcal{T}_{stand}$, it must be able to be written as a union of basis elements of $\mathcal{B}$. If that can be done, then by definition the set is in $\mathcal{T}_{stand}$ and is by definition open.

If we consider the set $A = (\frac{1}{2},1)$, we must check if this set can be written as a union of basis elements from $\mathcal{B}$. We can write $A$ as $(.5, .7) \cup (.6, 1)$. Hence, it a union of basis elements and thus open in $\mathcal{T}_{stand}$ (which means it is open in $\mathbb{R}$).

Now, we must check if it is open in the subspace topology on $Y$. That is, we must check if $A$ is in (and thus open) the collection $$\mathcal{T}_{y} := \{ Y \cap U \mid U \subset \mathcal{T}_{stand}\}$$ Or in terms of a basis, check if $A$ is union of basis elements of (if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{T}_{stand}$)$$\mathcal{B}_{Y} := \{Y \cap B \mid B \in \mathcal{B}\}$$

Can we write $A$ as the intersection of $[0,1]$ and some open intervals $(a,b)$? Yes - $(\frac{1}{2}, 1) = [0,1] \cap (\frac{1}{2},1)$. Hence, $A$ is in $\mathcal{T}_{Y}$ and is then open in the subspace topology on $Y$.

For the last part, i'm somewhat confused. The order topology on $Y$ with the order from $\mathbb{R}$? Meaning, a topology made up of open intervals $(a,b) = \{x\mid a < x<b\}$. How can this be applied to an interval $[0,1]$ ($Y$)?

---

Apparently it just means that the subset $Y$ gets the order which $\mathbb{R}$ has. Which is the standard order since we have the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. So this means we must show that $A$ can be written as an union of open intervals in $Y$. Which, by our previous answer, $A = (\frac{1}{2}, 1) = (\frac{1}{2}, .7)\cup (.6, 1) $

---

Also, anyone mind checking if I do the first two parts of the problem correctly?

Comment: Note that $(1/2,1)\ne (.5,.6)\cup (.6,1).$ There is a point missed.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: the order topology I think has intervals $(\leftarrow,b)$ and $(a,\to)$ as a subbasis, by definition. So $[\frac12,1)=(\leftarrow,1)$ is open.